# How to Retrieve a Specific value from a Specific List inside a Larger List?

Tags: python, list

Searches for my specific question have revealed examples looking for "all nth values in lists inside other lists" but all I want is ONE SINGLE value.

For example:  How would I retrieve ONLY the 2nd value in the 3rd list inside `mylist`?

```
mylist = [['dog', 'animal'],['daisy','flower'],['cat','animal']]
```

Comment: `mylist[2][1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = [['dog', 'animal'],['daisy','flower'],['cat','animal']]
>>> x = mylist[2][1]
>>> print x
animal
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JohnGordon!  Disappointed to have lost 7 rep points though (so far).  Was my question poorly worded?  As I said I did not see any other questions that matched the specifics of mine.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because it is such a basic question, yet you acted like it was quite hard to figure out.

Comment: I didn't think I was "acting" any particular way.  Just wanted to learn a specific skill that surprisingly didn't show up in any of my google or stack overflow searches.  Anyhow, now it will benefit others in the future.  And thanks again for your answer @John Gordon.

Comment: @user3309182 I am afraid your question does not that much show lack of search skill, rather lack of understanding of basics. Indexing a list is very basic operation. It is a bit like asking "how should I compute 1+1? Help, Google does not tell me."

Answer (score 1):

Just use the normal list syntax twice.

```
mylist[2][1]
```